# "Write Acces Violation" After Using malloc() Inside a Function

Tags: c, exception, multidimensional-array, struct, malloc

## Problem

I have custom struct for 2D Matrices. I'm using this struct inside a function to initialize a 2D matrix where every element value is set to 0. I've also have another function to print a matrix to terminal (for debugging purposes).

When I write the struct and the functions inside the `main.c`, they work. The problem is when I put them in a separate file and call them from that file I get a runtime error: `Exception thrown: write access violation`.

In my program I have 3 file: `main.c`, `my_lib.h`, `my_lib.c`. The struct is stored inside `my_lib.h`and the function is in `my_lib.c`. Inside `main.h`

I'm using Windows 10 & coding in Visual Studio 2017 v15.9.10

## Output

The program compiles but gives a runtime error `Exception thrown: write access violation`
[image]

## Edit:

Well, it seems it was my own fault that this was happening.

Actually, I was trying to run this code on my work computer. I've written the the original code on my personal computer where the `main.c`, `my_lib.h` & `my_lib.c` version was working. Then I copied the folder that I was working on and tried to continue on my work computer. Both my computer runs on Windows 10 OS and both have the same version of VS 2017.

On my personal computer the solution explorer was like:

[image]

But on my work computer, the solution opened as:

[image]

Everything, including the folder hierarchy are same on both computers. It seems, copying a project folder is not a good idea.

When I, created a new C project on my work computer and added the `my_lib.c`and `my_lib.h` manually, everything worked.

But I'm still curious why I was getting an Exception error... And how can I correct this problem of copying without creating a new project in VS?

## Code

### Just main.c ( Works)

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Matrix {
    int rows; // number of rows
    int cols; // number of columns
    double** data; // a pointer to an array of n_rows pointers to rows
}Matrix;

Matrix* make_matrix(int n_rows, int n_cols);
void print_matrix(Matrix* m);

int main() {

    Matrix* m1 = make_matrix(2, 5);

    print_matrix(m1);

    return 0;
}


// CREATE A MATRIX WITH N_ROWS AND N_COLUMNS AND INITIALIZE EACH VALUE AS 0
Matrix* make_matrix(int n_rows, int n_cols) {
    Matrix* matrix = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
    matrix->rows = n_rows;
    matrix->cols = n_cols;
    double** data = malloc(sizeof(double*) * n_rows);
    for (int x = 0; x < n_rows; x++) {
        data[x] = calloc(n_cols, sizeof(double));
    }
    matrix->data = data;
    return matrix;
}

// PRINT GIVEN MATRIX TO COMMAND LINE
void print_matrix(Matrix* m) {
    for (int x = 0; x < m->rows; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < m->cols; y++) {
            printf("%f", m->data[x][y]);
            printf("|");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

### main.c & function in seperate files (Throws an exception)

**main.c**

```
#include "my_lib.h"
int main(){
        // Create a 2 by 5 matrix & then print it to terminal
        Matrix* m1 = make_matrix(2, 5);
        print_matrix(m1);
        return 0;
}
```

**my_lib.h**

```
#pragma once

// Our custom 2D matrix struct
typedef struct Matrix {
    int rows; // number of rows
    int cols; // number of columns
    double** data; // a pointer to an array of n_rows pointers to rows
}Matrix;

Matrix* make_matrix(int n_rows, int n_cols);
void print_matrix(Matrix* m);
```

**my_lib.c**

```
#include "my_lib.h"
#include <stdio.h>

// CREATE A MATRIX WITH N_ROWS AND N_COLUMNS AND INITIALIZE EACH VALUE AS 0
Matrix* make_matrix(int n_rows, int n_cols) {
    Matrix* matrix = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
    matrix->rows = n_rows;
    matrix->cols = n_cols;
    double** data = malloc(sizeof(double*) * n_rows);
    for (int x = 0; x < n_rows; x++) {
        data[x] = calloc(n_cols, sizeof(double));
    }
    matrix->data = data;
    return matrix;
}

// PRINT GIVEN MATRIX TO COMMAND LINE
void print_matrix(Matrix* m) {
    for (int x = 0; x < m->rows; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < m->cols; y++) {
            printf("%f", m->data[x][y]);
            printf("|");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: @xing they're all in the same folder

Comment: Doesn't matter that they're all the same folder. At the point where main() calls make_matrix(), it doesn't yet know make_matrix's definition.

What happens if you add the following line to my_lib.h?

Matrix* make_matrix(int n_rows, int n_cols);

Comment: For good measure, you should also include `<stdlib.h>` to get the correct prototypes of `m/calloc`.

Comment: @GraemeCole I'm sorry, when I copied the code I forgot to add the function prototype declarations. I've edited the question by adding them to the header file.

Comment: If you use a standard C compiler instead, this wouldn't even compile. But hey, it's only been 20 years since C99 was released, maybe we should give MS more time to adapt.

Comment: @OguzCanbek you forgot `#include <stdlib.h>`. Didn't you get any compiler warnings?

Comment: Garbage MSVC surprises ag... no one at all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason you get the crash is not related at all to the fact that you have one or two .c files in your project but it's because you forgot to include `<stdlib.h>` in `my_lib.c`.

This triggers following warnings:

> my_lib.c(8) : warning C4013: 'malloc' undefined; assuming extern
> returning int
>  my_lib.c(13): warning C4013: 'calloc' undefined;
> assuming extern returning int
>  my_lib.c(13): warning C4047: '=':
> 'double *' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
> my_lib.c(8): warning C4047: 'initializing': 'Matrix *' differs in
> levels of indirection from 'int'
>  my_lib.c(11): warning C4047:
> 'initializing': 'double **' differs in levels of indirection from
> 'int'

You get away with it on a 32 bit build because the size of `int` is the same as the size of a pointer.

On the other hand if you build your program as 64 bit program, the warnings become really relevant, because now pointers are 64 bits wide, but as the compiler assumes that `malloc` etc. return `int`s (32 bit values), everything get messed up.

**Actually these warnings should be considered as errors.**

Here you decide if you want a 32 or a 64 bit build:

[image]

Add `#include <stdlib.h>` here in `my_lib.c`:

```
#include "my_lib.h"
#include <stdlib.h>   // <<<<<<<<<<<<<
#include <stdio.h>


// CREATE A MATRIX WITH N_ROWS AND N_COLUMNS AND INITIALIZE EACH VALUE AS 0
Matrix* make_matrix(int n_rows, int n_cols) {
  Matrix* matrix = malloc(sizeof(Matrix));
  ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and about the detailed explanation about 32 bit and 64 bit programs :) I have also another newbie question: should I also include the `<stdlib.h>` to my `main.c`or because I've added it to `my_lib.c`, it is not necessary?

Comment: @OguzCanbek no, it's not necessary, unless you use one of the functions declared in `stdlib.h` in `main.c`, which is not the case so far.