# C malloc struct throws memory violation exception (barebones example)

Tags: c

Here is the example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct nums {
    int x;
    int y;
};

int main() {
    struct nums *ball = malloc(sizeof *ball * 4);
    ball[0].x = 2;
    printf("%d", ball[0].x);
    free(ball);
};
```

Error Details:

```
Exception thrown: write access violation.
**ball** was 0x6E919550.
```

I am very new to C and I would really appreciate someone to explain what specifically I am telling the computer to do here, why it is incorrect and also show me the correct way of doing this. Thanks.

EDIT:
This seems to be functional code but does not run when I compile and run it in VS16 why could this be?

Comment: You should do `sizeof(struct nums)` instead of `*ball`. This is a legit question why people downvote?

Comment: what is the exact error you are getting, please paste it here.

Comment: Please review the question guidelines and consider changing your question to focus on a single and definitively answerable issue.

Comment: The change of ```*ball``` to ```struct nums``` does not change the error received .;(

Comment: @possum The issue is it causes an memory violation exception?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with `sizeof *ball`. In fact, many people prefer it over `sizeof(struct nums)`. It does not matter that `ball` is uninitialized since `sizeof` is a compile-time operation.

Comment: `You should do sizeof(struct nums) instead of *ball` No, I would advise to prefer `*ball` instead of `sizeof(struct nums)`, so that when you later refactor the code and change `ball` type, you don't have to track and change each `malloc` statement.

Comment: @Ripytide Did you `#include <stdlib.h>`? See ex. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44504429/c-write-access-violation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55454761/write-acces-violation-after-using-malloc-inside-a-function

Comment: @KamilCuk it's more comprehensive and clear to use `struct nums` than searching for the definition of `*ball` but that is opinion based I guess.

Comment: There's `#include <stdio.h>` in your code. For `malloc` you need also `#include <stdlib.h>`. Add `#include <stdlib.h>` on top of your source file (above or below `stdio` one) and recompile and run your program again - does the problem solve itself then?

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk that fixes it, I will now go learn about ```stdlib.h``` ;)

Comment: @TonyTannous The point of using `sizeof *ball` is that you do *not* need to go searching for the declaration.  `sizeof *ball` is guaranteed to be correct, but `sizeof(struct foo)` is wrong if ball is not a pointer to struct foo.  `sizeof *ball` is the better idiom.

Comment: First thing you should do is to always compile with `-Wall -Wextra` and pay attention to the warnings.

Comment: @TonyTannous `sizeof *ball` is better.  It is easier to code right the first time, easier to review and maintain than `sizeof(struct nums)`.  The "more comprehensive" argument is simple more to get wrong.

Comment: @Ripytide Whoever or whatever text suggested `struct nums *ball = malloc(sizeof *ball * 4);` is more up to date than others.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yes, I realized after that it was because OP hadn't included stdlib, stupid of me to ignore such an obvious thing. I'll delete my comment to avoid further confusion.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I crafted this short example myself and used ```* ball``` due to me learning about it here on SO when troubleshooting. I will go ahead and pat myself on the back :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most likely problem is a missing declaration for `malloc()`.  You should add the line

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

at the top of your code.

Without this line, the compiler may assume that `malloc` returns `int`.  But if you're on a 64-bit platform, with 32-bit ints but 64-bit pointers, this will fail pretty badly.  Your pointer variable `ball` is likely to end up holding just 32 of the 64 bits which `malloc` tried to return, with the other 32 scraped off.  `ball` will therefore be an invalid pointer, leading to the exception you saw.

Did you get any warnings?  My compiler complains

```
warning: implicitly declaring library function 'malloc'
note: include the header <stdlib.h>
```

Or, you might have gotten a message like

```
warning: implicit declaration of function 'malloc' is invalid in C99
```

If you got warnings like these, please don't ignore them, and do learn what they mean: they're definitely things you care about.  And if you *didn't* get warnings like these, you should figure out how to enable them in your compiler.  (Or if that's not possible, you should strongly consider switching to a better compiler, if at all possible.) Modern C programming practice definitely considers this error to be one worth warning about.  And there are *lots* of mistakes like this that are easy to make, that are frustrating to debug, and that a good compiler will warn you about, at least if you let it.